# Питон - Дамп памяти и сохранение данных в файл

Tags: python

Я сейчас задам какой то очень generic вопрос.

Вот есть у меня программа, и мне нужно что бы все её данные и все переменные были выгружены на локальный диск. То есть вот прям как есть, вместе с экземплярами класса - объектами и всеми их значениями. Как это правильно сделать?

Я имею ввиду как сделать дамп памяти?

Кода пока еще нет, поскольку я не знаю откуда начинать копать эту тему.

Comment: Уточните, какая цель. Если нужно для отладки - это один вопрос, если нужно при следующем запуске загрузить все обратно в память и продолжить выполнение с того места, на котором оно было прервано - другой.

Comment: Возможно вам нужно изучить git.

Comment: @Bol4onok git тут вообще никакой стороной

Comment: @Эникейщик Тогда я не понял, что требуется в вопросе.

Comment: globals() в pickle?))

Comment: да, задача восстановить переменные, связи, и их значения после прерывания работы скрипта.